# Python Simple Cookie and Python Stack

Tags: python

I made  a simple cookie and i want to store a python stack object.

```
C = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
arr = []
class Test:
 num = None
for x in range(10):
 test = Test()
 test.num = x
 arr.append(test)
 C['myCookie'] = arr # i want to do something like this
 arr = C['myCookie']
```

can any one tell me a way to do it . to store an array in python cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general purpose object-to-string-and-back conversions, you could use the *pickle* module:

```
C['myCookie'] = pickle.dumps(arr)
arr_restored = pickle.loads(C['myCookie'].value)
```

Keep in mind that unpickling untrusted cookies represents a security risk.  If that is an issue for you, then you will need to adopt some other strategy for turning an array of user defined object into a string and for converting it back.

Comment: if pickle.loads(C['myCookie']) != None:
     bread_crumb_stack =      pickle.loads(str(self.session.get('bread_crumb')) this code segment gives an error when it tried to check none for a cookie . it throws KeyError .  how to get this thing done

Comment: your solution is not working . it gives TypeError
TypeError: expected read buffer, Morsel found

Comment: I forgot the ".value" to pull the value out of the Morsel.